# Error running Pax Web Jetty

Tags: osgi, equinox, pax-web

I'm running Pax-Web in equinox (org.eclipse.osgi_3.5.0 bundle).

I'm running pax-web-jetty-bundle_3.0.2 bundle

When starting this jetty bundle (pax web jetty) the folling error arises:

```
The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.osgi.framework.wiring; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
```

I can't find which bundle provides (export) the package org.osgi.framework.wiring.
org.eclipse.osgi is not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package is available since OSGi 4.3 (as much as I remember) in OSGi core. You use too old version of equinox that does not support this version of OSGi spec. Use equinox 3.7.1 or newer and the package will be there for sure.